# rank of a matrix with Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $e_j$ be the $j$th column of $I_n$ with $j=1,...,n$. Also, let $A$ and $B$ be $m \times p$ and $m \times r$ matrices, respectively. Then, what is the rank of $X$ given by
\begin{equation}
X=[e_i \otimes A, \ B \otimes e_j].
\end{equation}
My conjecture is $rank(X)=rank([A, \ B])=rank(A)+rank(B)$ since it seems that $(e_i \otimes A)$ and $(B \otimes e_j)$ will not span the same column space. But I'm not sure and don't know how to prove...

Comment: It is not generally the case that $\operatorname{rank}([A \ \  B]) = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$. For instance, consider the case where the columns of $B$ are multiples of the columns of $A$.

Comment: If $i \neq j$, then it certainly holds that
$$
\operatorname{rank}[e_i \otimes A, \ \ e_j \otimes B]  = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B),
$$
but with the order of the Kronecker product swapped it's less clear

Comment: Even in the case that $p = r = 1$, different things can happen: if $A = e_j$ and $B = e_i$, then this matrix has rank 1, which incidentally is less than $\operatorname{rank}[A\ \ B] = 2$. On the other hand, whenever $A$ is not a multiple of $e_j$ or $B$ is not a multiple of $e_i$, this matrix has rank $2$.

Comment: As a further note to my first comment, it is always the case however that $\operatorname{rank}[A\ \ B] \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Comment: As a further note to my second comment, if $i = j$, then 
$$
X = e_i \otimes [A\ \ B],
$$
which has rank equal to $\operatorname{rank}[A\ \ B]$.

Comment: Many thanks. I also considered swapping the order of Kronecker product, but it was not trivial issue....

Comment: So does that answer your question, or are there still any lingering issues to be addressed here?